# Monaco editor change double quote to single quote character

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

As my custom language uses single quote (') and not double quote (") character for strings, I would like to change a double quote into two single quote characters on user input. Is this possible in monaco editor and what is the best way to do it ?

So for example if the user inputs this " it will automatically changed to this ''. The only time this is not the case would be inside of two single quote characters (' " ').

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough I am not sure if registerOnTypeFormattingEditProvider is the best method to do this here is the code how I managed to accomplish this task:

```
 // changes the double quote charachter to two single quote characters
monaco.languages.registerOnTypeFormattingEditProvider(clarionLanguage, {
    autoFormatTriggerCharacters: ['"'],
    provideOnTypeFormattingEdits: (model, position, character, options, token) => {

        // if inside string quotes then allow double quote character
        let quotes: monaco.editor.FindMatch[] = model.findMatches(`'([^'])*'`, true, true, true, null, true);
        if (quotes.length > 0) {
            for (let quote of quotes) {
                if (quote && (position.column >= quote.range.startColumn && position.column <= quote.range.endColumn)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        return [
            {
                range: {
                    startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                    startColumn: position.column - 1,
                    endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                    endColumn: position.column
                },
                text: `''`
            }
        ];
    }
});
```

---

This here is a much better solution (suggested by rcjsuen and alexandrudima on GitHub):

```
 // change the double quotes to two single quotes
    editor.onDidType(text => {
        if (text === '"') {
            let selection = editor.getSelection();
            let range = new monaco.Range(selection.startLineNumber, selection.startColumn - 1, selection.endLineNumber, selection.endColumn);
            let id = { major: 1, minor: 1 };
            let op = { identifier: id, range, text: "''", forceMoveMarkers: true };

            editor.getModel().pushEditOperations([], [op], undefined);

            editor.setSelection(selection);
        }
    });
```